# libgdx flickering on while testing on android but no issue with the desktop version

Tags: java, libgdx

My project runs perfectly fine on the desktop version but it keeps on flickering when testing on android.

i have done lots of research about this and apparently the problem cause double buffering. but still i couldnt find any solution for that yet. there was a guy that sugested using "render to texture" but i couldnt find any example about that for libgdx.

i want to know if there is a way to solve this issue

in case you wanna know about my code i have a draw spritebatch out side the render function where i had to do that to go with my game logic and that is what cuasing the double buffering

```
public void create(){
...
    Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false);
    Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();

}

public void render() {      

    batch.begin();
    drawBoard();
    player();

    batch.end();

}
```

where my player function checks whos turn (player1/player2) then it checks legal moves then it draws the spritebatch according to that

```
public void player(){
    clickX=Gdx.input.getX();
    clickY=(Gdx.input.getY()-Gdx.graphics.getHeight())*-1;


            if(turn==true){
                player = "player1";
                if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){

                        //System.out.println("avalible");

                        if(rect.isEmpty()){
                            batch.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                            addLineNew(clickX, clickY);
                            plr1++;
                            System.out.println(plr1);
                            turn=false;

                        }else {
                            for (int i=0; i<rect.size(); i++){
                                if(rect.get(i).contains(clickX, clickY)){
                                    System.out.println("line exsit");
                                    break;
                                }else{
                                    batch.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                                    tempScore = score1;
                                    turnC=added.size();
                                    addLineNew(clickX,clickY);
                                    System.out.println("rect size "+rect.size());
                                    if(turnC>added.size()){
                                    calculateScore();
                                    }
                                    plr1++;
                                    System.out.println(plr1);
                                    if (score1>tempScore){
                                        turn=true;
                                    }else if (turnC>added.size()){
                                    turn=false;
                                    }else{
                                        turn=true;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
```

this is for player1 for player 2 is pretty much the same

```
public void addLineNew(float x, float y){
    float clickx=x;
    float clicky=y;
    outterLoop:
    for (int i=0; i<added.size(); i++){

            for(int j=0; j<Xpoints.length; j++){
                if(added.get(i).contains(clickx, clicky) && added.get(i).x==Xpoints[j]+16){
                    batch.draw(lineH, added.get(i).x, added.get(i).y, sizeH.x, sizeH.y);
                    rect.add(added.get(i));
                    added.remove(i);
                    System.out.println("sizz///"+added.size());
                    break outterLoop;
                }
                else if (added.get(i).contains(clickx, clicky) && added.get(i).x==Xpoints[j]){
                    batch.draw(line, added.get(i).x, added.get(i).y, sizeV.x, sizeV.y);
                    rect.add(added.get(i));
                    added.remove(i);
                    System.out.println("sizz///"+added.size());
                    break outterLoop;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("line is not availble play again");

                }
            }
```

add line function where im using it to draw

Comment: also i tried putting the content of player() inside the render function but still flickering

Comment: AFAIK double buffering should actually prevent flickering and it should be working by default (I never had any issuis with flickering). Do you use vSync?

Comment: no im not not using it.. would it solve the issue?

Comment: It might, it's just a start configuration and it's only available for desktop, but you can try. If it won't help, you should show us more code give a more detailed description about the flickering. As I said, I'm not doing any special magic and I don't have flickering

Comment: the desktop is working perfectly fine the flickering occurs only on android.. it seems like there is three frames and each click it renders out one of them.. the code is pretty long ill add some other parts to the question

Comment: btw the game is dots and box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did something wrong. :)
Try creating that demo project with bucket and rain drops and see does it also has flickering screen.

If it also flickers then you should try your app on some other phone/tablet.

But if it doesn't then compare main rendering steps (and their order) in that demo with your app.

What I do when I'm desperate is that I start with working code and start changing it peace by peace until it becomes identical with non-working or actually at some point it will stop working, so you'll know what you changed last..